# Animate tiled sprite in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I have animated tiled sprite.At first time i want to animate 4 till 7 frame 4 time.and at next instant i want to continuously move 0 to 3 frame .i am using this code to do my job but cant accomplish it

```
playerSprite.animate(new long[] { 100,100,100,100}, 4, 7, 2);
playerSprite.animate(new long[] { 100,100,100,100}, 0, 4, true);
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding "animate 4 till 7 frame 4 time." Could you add some more detail to this question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my suggestion you have to use animation listener for this purpose. When first animation completes its work then you have to start another animation. Following is the code snippet that helps you.

```
animate(new long[] {100,100,100,100}, 4, 7, false, new IAnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStarted(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                int pInitialLoopCount) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationLoopFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                int pRemainingLoopCount, int pInitialLoopCount) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationFrameChanged(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                int pOldFrameIndex, int pNewFrameIndex) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {
            // start your second animation
        }
    });
```

Using this way you have to call your other animation in onAnimationFinished method